# toPromise() says Module not found

Tags: angular, typescript

Error in ./scr/app/git-search.service.ts

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise' in 'C:\Users\funky\angular-fundamentals\src\app

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular 6, it may be because rxjs path has been modified.
You should write only "rxjs" as the path. 
You can find more information at this link:

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

I hope I have helped you